# Fairmont Orchid Gold room or Mauna Lani Bay Oceanfront room?

Tags: hawaii

I can't decide which would be more enjoyable and worth the money for our anniversary and babymoon trip to the big island of Hawaii in a few weeks. The gold part of the resort seems like you're treated like royalty, but it's $150 more per night than mauna lani.